# Get a user profile by his email address in Bot Framework Composer People Skill

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, bots, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework Composer. I have connected the people skill to my AD.
How can I search for a user by it's email address?
I know that for a search by name bot uses a variable `contactName`, what variable would it use for a search by email address?

Comment: Do you use microsoft graph api? Could you share some code?

Comment: @user2250152 I'm using Microsoft Graph blocks in Bot Framework Composer. Currently I'm getting: 

"Sorry, I couldn't find anyone named **e-mail address** in your organization. Please try again.

I'm trying to make the flow understand it's not a person name but an email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 'People' template in Bot Framework Composer, then just investigate 'OnIntent (GetProfile)' trigger. It can search people by e-mail.

For example to trigger it you can just ask bot something like 'get me user@example.com' or 'please show me user@example.com'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already did a walkaround and moved the logic to Azure Logic Apps!